# 19.10: How do I get the touchpad of a 2016 Asus E403SA to work?

Tags: drivers, kernel, touchpad, asus, 19.10

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 on a 2016 [Asus E403SA](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/E403SA/). The touchpad on this thing has never worked - did not when i installed 18.04 back in October 2019 and still does not work even with this upgrade I did about two weeks ago. It also broke on Windows 10 back in around March of 2018, which is when I stopped using the machine for a long time.

I looked through online and I have tried various solutions - i have libinput and synaptics installed (keyboard needs libinput), i don't think ndiswrapper does touchpads, ive tried reinserting kernel modules, i've even tried reinstalling to see if the original installation was bugged and none of the other solutions ive tried helped either. From what I read, this should be working by default. on the asus website, however, there was no driver for Linux - it was windows-only.

this is my xinput: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/412751703667113985/673592165552619520/Screenshot-20200202131231-732x233.png

this is my cat /proc/bus/input/devices:
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/412751703667113985/673592841561178133/unknown.png?width=599&height=526
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/412751703667113985/673592956447490048/unknown.png?width=412&height=525
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/412751703667113985/673593090707030031/unknown.png
My kernel version is 5.3.0-29-generic.

If any other info is needed I will put it here ASAP.

According to the Arch Wiki, this should be working by default using the synaptics driver but at this point im pretty sure the touchpad is just plain not supported, the kernel is bugged or the touchpad is physically broken. However i want to try everything before giving up. Is there a way to get this to work? Also, how do I check if its physically broken? It doesn't appear to be.

Comment: " It also broke on Windows 10" - did you mean the _touchpad_ failed in Windows 10, or something else failed in Windows 10?

Comment: The touchpad failed. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: If the touchpad failed in Windows 10 and you can't revive it in Ubuntu, it's a hardware issue. I would contact Asus support and ask them where their repair manual is. Remove the touchpad cable and reconnect it, as cable/connector issues are very frequent.